# How to reference an ID to delete

Tags: php, jquery

I´m trying to remove a div with jquery but I don´t know how can I refer to the ID because it´s a PHP var: id="delete$count"

My Javascript code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function deleteFile(fname,directory)
 {
 $.ajax({ url: "delete_img.php",
    data: {"file":fname,"directory":directory},
    type: 'post',
    success: function(output) {
      alert(output);

    $('div').remove();
             }
     });
   }
  </script>
```

My PHP code:

```
     $count=1;
     echo '<div class="gallery-item" id="delete$count"></div>';
     echo "<div><a class='ico ico-delete' rel='9' rev='2' href='#'onclick='deleteFile(\"$file\",\"$directory\")'>
    </a></div>";                    
    $count++;
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the below will send `delete$count` verbatim to the response stream without evaluating `$count`

```
echo '<div class="gallery-item" id="delete$count"></div>';
```

Change it to

```
echo "<div class='gallery-item' id='delete$count'></div>";
```

so as for PHP to interpolate `$count`.

Try then passing this as a third parameter to your function as

```
echo "<div><a class='ico ico-delete' rel='9' rev='2' href='#'onclick='deleteFile(\"$file\",\"$directory\",\"delete$count\")'>
```

and collect its value in a third argument to

```
function deleteFile(fname,directory, deletecount) {  }
```

and replace

```
$('div').remove();
```

by `$('#' + deletecount).remove();`

Comment: It works!!! fantastic!! very clear and easy explained. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

If i understund correctly, you want to achieve the following:

1. use AJAX to tell server to delete file
2. remove same file from current view without reloading page

If you read file information from database, i would suggest you to use row-id or something similar as 'gallery-item' ids, and as argument for deleteFile() function.
In case you dont, you can use paired value of $directory and $file instead.

```
 echo '<div class="gallery-item" id="'. $directory . $file . '" ></div>';
 echo "<div><a class='ico ico-delete' rel='9' rev='2' href='#'onclick='deleteFile(\"$file\",\"$directory\")'>
</a></div>";
```

With this, you can replace your    `$('div').remove()` with`$('#'+directory+fname).remove()`